# How to create a wrap with ChoiceChip with custom labels in Flutter

Tags: flutter, android-chips

I'm learning **flutter** but there are some things that I cannot find anywhere.

For example, I want to make a **group of ChoiceChips**, similar to the picture

[image]

but I don't know how to put **custom labels** in this kind of chips.

How can I make it possible?

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 class MyThreeOptions extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
   _MyThreeOptionsState createState() => _MyThreeOptionsState();
}

  class _MyThreeOptionsState extends State<MyThreeOptions> {
  int _value = 0;

  // ----What I want to appear----//
  /*void v (int index){
   switch (index){
   case 0: Text('Phones');
   break;

   case 1: Text('Computers');
   break;

   case 2: Text('Accessories');
   break;
   }}*/

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  spacing: 12.0,
  children: List<Widget>.generate(
  3,
      (int index) {
      return ChoiceChip(
       pressElevation: 0.0,
       selectedColor: Colors.blue,
       backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
       label: Text("item $index"),
       selected: _value == index,
       onSelected: (bool selected) {
        setState(() {
          _value = selected ? index : null;
        });
      },
    );
  },
 ).toList(),
 );}
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]

```
    int defaultChoiceIndex;
List<String> _choicesList = ['All', 'Pending', 'Accepted'];

    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    defaultChoiceIndex = 0;
  }

    Wrap(
      spacing: 8,
      children: List.generate(_choicesList.length, (index) {
        return ChoiceChip(
          labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          label: Text(
            _choicesList[index],
            style: Theme.of(context)
                .textTheme
                .bodyText2!
                .copyWith(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
          ),
          selected: defaultChoiceIndex == index,
          selectedColor: Colors.deepPurple,
          onSelected: (value) {
            setState(() {
              defaultChoiceIndex = value ? index : defaultChoiceIndex;
            });
          },
          // backgroundColor: color,
          elevation: 1,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: SizeConfig.widthMultiplier * 4),
        );
      }),
    );
```

Comment: Hello, what is `SizeConfig.widthMultiplier` here?

Comment: ohh it's nothing serious, I am using mediaQuery in my project for dynamic size, u can use any kind of double value here @Danny

Comment: Oh..okay! Thank you.

Comment: is there a way to change label color based on selected/not selected?

Answer (score 3):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class ChoiceChips extends StatefulWidget {
  final List chipName;
  ChoiceChips({Key key, this.chipName}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChoiceChipsState createState() => _ChoiceChipsState();
}

class _ChoiceChipsState extends State<ChoiceChips> {
  String _isSelected = "";

  _buildChoiceList() {
    List<Widget> choices = List();
    widget.chipName.forEach((item) {
      choices.add(Container(
        child: ChoiceChip(
          label: Text(item),
          labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          selectedColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
          backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          selected: _isSelected == item,
          onSelected: (selected) {
            setState(() {
              _isSelected = item;
            });
          },
        ),
      ));
    });
    return choices;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 5.0,
      runSpacing: 3.0,
      children: _buildChoiceList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope this helps! What I am looking for is how can I get the values of the selected chip so that I can store it to string where I am using this widget.

Answer (score 2):

You just need create your own widget with a layout of your desire and put as label of your Chip.

```
// Your custom widget...
class CustomChipLabel extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
              iconSize: 40.0,
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              onPressed: null),
          Text("My Custom Chip", style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,

          ),),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}

Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[
    ChoiceChip(
      selected: _isSelected
      label: CustomChipLabel(), // your custom label widget
    ),
  ],
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do not understand how with this method you can have more than one chip. Would you have to create a widget for each chip ?. I think there has to be some other more efficient way.

Comment: Yes you need create one widget for each chip label. But if the label will be the same in many chips you can use the same instance for them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have discovered a way, but I think there has to be some more efficient, creating a list of Strings and passing the values, but I can not encode it. If someone knows any more efficient way to carry out this action, their contribution is appreciated.

```
class MyThreeOptions extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyThreeOptionsState createState() => _MyThreeOptionsState();
 }

class _MyThreeOptionsState extends State<MyThreeOptions> {
int _value = 0;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Wrap(
  alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
  spacing: 12.0,
  children: <Widget>[
    ChoiceChip(
      pressElevation: 0.0,
      selectedColor: Colors.blue,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      label: Text("Phones"),
      selected: _value == 0,
      onSelected: (bool selected) {
        setState(() {
          _value = selected ? 0 : null;
        });
      },
    ),
    ChoiceChip(
      pressElevation: 0.0,
      selectedColor: Colors.blue,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      label: Text("Computers"),
      selected: _value == 1,
      onSelected: (bool selected) {
        setState(() {
          _value = selected ? 1 : null;
        });
      },
    ),
    ChoiceChip(
      pressElevation: 0.0,
      selectedColor: Colors.blue,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100],
      label: Text("Accesories"),
      selected: _value == 2,
      onSelected: (bool selected) {
        setState(() {
          _value = selected ? 2 : null;
        });
      },
    ),
  ],
);
}
}
```